# Install other packages in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio

When I installed Visual Studio 2017, I had the options of which bits I wanted to install, so I chose C#, Xamarin and some other ones.

However, I did not install the C++ stuff. Is there any way I can get all that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way. Go to your VS2017 installer (find it in Start > V > Visual Studio Installer) and from there on you can add/remove/repair the modules. Be prepared for some downloading time if you have not done the "offline installation".